# Jquery change image on hove and set default one on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this question was asked before many times but I can't find a solution that fits my case, so let's start.

I use `Bootstrap` nav pills to navigate through content. The structure looks like this:

```
<ul id="mytabs" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">
  <li class="option1"><a href="#option1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><img src="/image1" id="image1-background"</a></li>
  <li class="option2"><a href="#option2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><img src="/image2" id="image2-background"</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade id="option1">
        <p>Content for first option</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade id="option2">
        <p>Content for second option</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is fairly simple but I'll explain more. The main idea behind `.nav-pills` section is that they have images that should change on hover and mouse over.
I do it like this (from what I tried it's the closest thing I need):

```
$(".option1").hover(function() {
    $('#image1-background').attr('src', 'different-image1.png');
}, function() {
    $('#image1-background').attr('src', 'image1.png');
});
```

And it works as I want, i.e it changes images the correct way. Trouble comes when I really need `different-image1.png` to stay when I mouse over to `.tab-content > .tab-pane id="option1"` section, but obviously it doesn't work because when I mouse over, the image changes, so how to keep an image I hovered on ('`different-image1.png`' in this case) to be displayed when my cursor is in corresponding tab?

I tried to do this:

```
$('#mytabs a[href="#option1"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        $('#image1-background').attr('src', 'different-image1.png');
});
```

But it didn't work as well other scripts `Bootstrap` provides though. Here's also jsfiddle to get you a better grasp on what I'm talking about - https://jsfiddle.net/adaccount/9rdum27v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a wrapper div to wrap both tabs and tab-content, register mouse enter event for tab option only, and register mouse leave for wrapper to reset to default.

I updated your example:

https://jsfiddle.net/9rdum27v/1/

```
d
```